# Solving an Exact Equation: $x y^2 -10 x y + (x^2 y -5 x^2 -5 ) y' = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the exact equation
>   $$x y^2 -10 x y + (x^2 y -5 x^2 -5 ) y' = 0$$

$F(x,y) = c$

Ok I am not sure what to do.

I try and find $\Psi x = M$

So

integrate $(x y^2 -10 x y)\, dx$ and get

$$\frac{1}{2}x^2 y^2  - 5 x^2 y^2$$

Wolfram alpha tells me I am correct

then I add the unknown function of $y$

$$\frac{1}{2}x^2 y^2 - 5 x^2 y^2 + h(y)$$

and then take the partial of that with respect to $y$

$$x^2 y - 10 x^2 y + h'(y)$$

and I am supposed to set it equal to the other part from the original problem right?
So I know

$$x^2 y -5 x^2 -5 =  x^2 y - 10 x^2 y + h'(y)$$

BUT here I am stuck. That $-5$ in the first part is throwing me off. There isn't a function of $y$ I can add to make them equal is there? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: $\int 10 xy dx = 5x^2 y$, not $5x^2 y^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you integrate $xy^2-10xy$ with respect to $x$, you should get $\frac{x^2y^2}{2}-5x^2y+h(y)$; you somehow ended up with an extra $y$ on the middle part, which is what messed up the rest.

Comment: Oh lol. Thanks! Its always something isn't it...

Comment: So I got x^2 y - 5 x^2 - 5y = c Is this correct?

Comment: Appears correct to me.  To verify, you could always take the derivative of the left-hand side, df/dx dx/dx + df/dy dy/dx and you should end up with the same thing as your original equation.

Comment: The online form I have to enter it into said it was wrong. Any chance you could take a look and see if you get something different?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't realize-you missed a y on the middle term, it should just be -5x^2y.

Comment: Thank you a ton. If anyone else is reading this I also didn't integrate the x^2 y part too in addition to the -5^x.